# Реализация получения данных из сокета

Tags: python, сокет

Пытаюсь реализовать **постоянное** получение данных из сокета на Python. Вот код (минимально воспроизводимый пример):

```
import socket
import time

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 12345))

while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
    print(data)
    time.sleep(3)

sock.close()
```

...но что-то мне кажется, что данный вариант это скорее "костыль". Можно его как-то улучшить? Я очень начинающий разработчик, так что не судите строго!

Comment: из-за `while True` костыль? что именно смущает в этом примере?

Comment: @Вадим Александру смущает именно наличие `time.sleep()`. Ведь во многих клиентах используется конструкция `if not data:` и `break`. Т.е. ожидается пока `sock.recv(1024).decode('utf8')` вернет пустую строку...

Comment: ну так и используйте `if not data: break`, я дал вам внизу хороший пример реализации, хватайте

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы разобраться с тем, как создать прослушиватель по сокету, я написал для вас маленький пример. Для работы нам необходимо иметь серверную часть и клиентскую часть. Для примера я реализую то и то.

**`Server.py`** - наш сервер.

```
import socket

def start_server():
    server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('localhost', 12345)
    server_sock.bind(server_address)
    server_sock.listen(1)

    print("Сервер запущен, ожидание соединения")

    try:
        connection, client_address = server_sock.accept()
        print("Соединение установлено с: ", client_address)

        while True:
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break

            # Преобразуем полученные данные в верхний регистр
            response = data.decode().upper()
            print(f'здесь данные: {data}')
            print(f'А здесь сообщение {response}')
            # Отправляем данные обратно клиенту
            connection.sendall(response.encode())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Сервер прерван пользователем")
    finally:
        connection.close()
        server_sock.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
```

**`main.py`** - наш клиент

```
import socket

def send_data_to_server(sock, message):
    try:
        # Отправляем сообщение на сервер
        sock.sendall(message.encode())

        # Получаем и выводим ответ от сервера
        response = sock.recv(1024)
        print("Получено с сервера: ", response.decode())

    except Exception as e:
        print("Ошибка:", e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Создаем сокет объект
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Устанавливаем параметры подключения (адрес и порт сервера)
    server_address = ('localhost', 12345)

    try:
        # Подключаемся к серверу
        sock.connect(server_address)

        while True:
            # Читаем пользовательский ввод
            message = input("Напишите сообщение (или 'exit' для выхода): ")

            if message.lower() == "exit":
                break

            # Отправляем введенное сообщение на сервер и получаем ответ
            send_data_to_server(sock, message)

    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("Отказ в подключении. Убедитесь, что сервер запущен.")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Прервано пользователем.")
    finally:
        sock.close()
```

Для работы необходимо сначала запустить `server.py`, а затем запустить `main.py`, далее можно из консоли `main.py` отправлять сообщения на сервер и получать обработанный ответ. В данном случае сервер просто форматирует строку в заглавные символы. Напишем в консоли клиента `hello` и отправим. Получим следующие выводы в терминалах:

`server.py`

```
PS D:\projects\python\24.07.23> py .\server.py
Сервер запущен, ожидание соединения
Соединение установлено с:  ('127.0.0.1', 53065)
здесь данные: b'hello'
А здесь сообщение HELLO
```

`main.py`

```
PS D:\projects\python\24.07.23> py .\main.py
Напишите сообщение (или 'exit' для выхода): hello
Получено с сервера:  HELLO
Напишите сообщение (или 'exit' для выхода):
```

P.S. Я могу лишь предполагать, почему был выбран порт `53065`, вероятно потому что он самый свободный для обмена данными.